# malformed record data: github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.0/go.mod

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

i'm trying to get the go package using command `go get gorm.io/driver/postgres`

but the result is always like this

```
go get: gorm.io/driver/postgres@none updating to
        gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.0 requires
        github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.11.0 requires
        github.com/jackc/pgconn@v1.8.1 requires
        github.com/jackc/pgmock@v0.0.0-20190831213851-13a1b77aafa2 requires
        github.com/jackc/pgtype@v0.0.0-20190828014616-a8802b16cc59 requires
        github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.0.0-pre1.0.20190824185557-6972a5742186 requires
        github.com/jackc/pgtype@v0.0.0-20190824184912-ab885b375b90 requires
        github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.0: verifying go.mod: github.com/lib/pq@v1.1.0/go.mod: malformed record data
```

i have cleaned my cache and still getting the same error. what should i do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an indirect dependency to [https://github.com/lib/pq/tree/v1.0.0] which has a malformed go mod file. The go version is not mentioned in that. The latest release is v1.10.2. There is nothing to do in your code since its indirect, you can use a version of your direct dependecy `gorm.io/driver/postgres` which uses an updated version of this  `lib/pq/tree` library or raise an issue in the git for `lib/pq/tree`.